# How insert values with static Id in Entity Framework for SQL Server CE?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I am trying fill new table in manually migration.

I successfully created the table, but I have trouble with inserting.

```
var sql = @"CREATE TABLE[DefaultSettings] ([Id] int IDENTITY (1, 1)  NOT NULL
                                           , [Tag] nvarchar(63)  NOT NULL
                                           , [ValueInt] int NULL
                                           , [ValueDate] datetime NULL
                                           , [ValueChar] nvarchar(255)  NULL);";
dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);

sql = @"ALTER TABLE[DefaultSettings] ADD CONSTRAINT[PK_DefaultSettings] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])";
dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);

sql = @"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [DefaultSettings] ON;
INSERT INTO [DefaultSettings] ([Id], [Tag], [ValueInt], [ValueDate],[ValueChar]) VALUES (1, N'DefaultArea', 58, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO [DefaultSettings] ([Id], [Tag], [ValueInt], [ValueDate],[ValueChar]) VALUES (2, N'DefaultFarm', 52, NULL, NULL);
GO";

dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);
return;
```

For second `ExecuteSqlCommand` I get errors

> Error statement insert

I am try separate all commands in sql variable by GO - I know that SQL Server CE cannot into multiple `SqlCommand`.

But I got error like "error statement GO".

Any ideas?

Comment: I would start adding the spaces between TABLE and [DefaultSettings] as well between CONSTRAINT and [DefaultSettings] And GO has no meaning when you run this from code. It is understood only by the IDE of SQL Server Management Studio as separator between commands

Comment: Spaces don't important...
So, for `sql = @"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [DefaultSettings] ON;
INSERT INTO [DefaultSettings] ([Id], [Tag], [ValueInt], [ValueDate],[ValueChar]) VALUES (1, N'DefaultArea', 58, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO [DefaultSettings] ([Id], [Tag], [ValueInt], [ValueDate],[ValueChar]) VALUES (2, N'DefaultFarm', 52, NULL, NULL);
";` got `There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 2,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = INSERT ]`

Comment: Then the error is in the third ExecuteSqlCommand? Well then you need to split those commands in 3 separate commands and do not forget to set the IDENTITY_INSERT OFF after the inserts

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Compact only allows a single statement per command, so you must use multiple calls to ExecuteSqlCommand, one per INSERT statement.

Comment: Ok. But, I think, I need execute `SET IDENTITY_INSERT [DefaultSettings] ON;` When I exec it in first sql statement, I got error for the second (insert) statement. So, I think, I need exec identity_insert and inserts in one statement. But I dont know, how...

Comment: Have you tried: dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction() ? Or TransactionScope?

Comment: Some sample code of how to use BeginTransaction here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456843(v=vs.113).aspx